# How to extract a substring from ', #' + 3 until ', # '+ 8 characters

Tags: python

I have a code to extract a substring from the `#` sign plus 7 characters:

```
text[text.find('#') + 1:text.find('#') + 7]
```

It was working fine, until one text had more that one `#` sign, so I realized I needed to look for the substring `, #` instead of `#`.

The text I have is: `Void - Compliance Plan #3, # 00002 (Voided)`

With my initial code I get `3, #` instead of `00002`.

I changed the code to:

```
text[text.find(', #') + 3:text.find(', #') + 10]
```

but I get `id - Co`.

Comment: you may benefit from regular expressions here!

Comment: what's your expected result?   00002 or what?

Comment: You almost certainly want to search for [a five digit number after a hash mark](https://regex101.com/r/4pGWRi/1) instead of finding individual letters and then adding a number.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you extract "until ', #' +8 characters" neither by using +7 nor by using +10 but by using +8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like `text.find(", #")` returns -1. Only then it would give you such result. "find" method returns -1 if there is no such phrase in string. Please check if inside find() inside brackets you have exactly ", #" (with space).

```
>>> text.find("XDD")
-1
>>> text[text.find(', #')+3:text.find(', #') + 10]
' 00002 '
```

Comment: I verify that it has the space. I added one more space and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code to find the index of the first occurrence of “, #” instead of just “#”.

```
text[text.find(', #') + 3:text.find(', #') + 9]
```

This will find the substring “, #” and then extract the 6 characters following it, giving you the expected result “00002”.

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression / pattern matching
`#\s+(\d{5})\s+` matches strings with a # then at least 1 space then 5 digits 0-9 and then at least 1 space.

```py
import re

txt = 'Void - Compliance Plan #3, # 00002 (Voided)'
pattern = r'#\s+(\d{5})\s+'
num = re.search(pattern, txt).group(1)

print(num)
# prints 00002
```